# How to detect non IEEE-754 float, and how to use them?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, standards, legacy

I'm writing classes for basic types, so that code is logically the same on multiple platforms and compilers (like `int_least16_t` for `int`). For fun! (I'm still a student.)
And I read this:

> [float [...] Matches IEEE-754 binary32 format **if supported.**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)

And what's worse:

> [Floating-point types **MAY** support special values:
> **∞**, NaN or -0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)

Which means that float **MAY** be unsigned... 
[edit: Yes it's difrent thing, but there is no: ",but must suport negative numbers". Yo, with out things like this in standart it may not suport normal 0...(I don't have specyfication.) [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72138837/can-floats-not-suport-negative-or-even-0)]

I know it's like with [__int128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088282/is-there-a-128-bit-integer-in-gcc), and the standard is just a standard,
but still...
IEEE-754 is from 1985, but some machines can be weird,
and some legacy hardware doesn't have a floating unit.

As I understand, float is mandatory (not optional like int16_t),
but can be in any standard, and any set of values can be possible?

---

Only thing we have are some macros ([`<cfloat>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cfloat)):

- `FLT_MIN`, `FLT_MAX` - Even if `FLT_MIN = IEEE-754::FLT_MIN`, float can be non IEEE-754.
  For example float with: flipped exponent with fraction...
- `FLT_RADIX` - Base system? If so, can help to write the exact value. But still, float can be 3 bit or 200 bit (in size)...
- `FLT_EPSILON` - (from 1 to next) We might use it (with base) to check fraction size...
- `FLT_MANT_DIG` - Is it "mantissa" digits / fraction size?
- `FLT_MAX_EXP` - Exponent filled with 1... in IEEE-754,
  but outside can be a random number?

If float is like IEEE-754 (sign, exponent, fraction), then it's easy,
but if -0 and NaN are optional then it **MAY** be different.
Because I can't tell them apart, I can't use bit representation
(in a safe manner). And if **∞** is optional, `float` is no longer a safe type.

The only way out I see is to add macro to compiler.

I know it's a theoretical problem, but I'm interested if there is any check possible or we all write implementation dependent code, when we use the `float` keyword?

---

Edit 2022 May 04:

I came up with this:

User eg. code:

```cpp
//User eg. code:

int main()
{
   float_M a = 1f;
   float_M b = 0f;
   std::cout << a/b; //should output infinty (IEEE-754)
}

//Code:

class float_M
{
public:
#ifdef __STDC_IEC_559__
   float data;
//...
   float_M operator/(float_M x){return float_M(data/x.data);}
//...
#else
   /*union{
      float data;
      struct{//For noSign case ("absolutly catastrofic" case)
         uint_least8_t sign : 1;
         uint_least8_t exponent : 8;
         uint_least32_t fraction : 23;
      }
   }*/ //no noSign case 
   float data;
//...
   float_M operator/(float_M x){return divide(this, x);}

//funtion pointer alert!
   static /*const (1*) */ float_M (*divide)(float_M a, float_M b) =
      /*std::numeric_limits<float>::is_signed ?(*/
         std::numeric_limits<float>::has_infinity ?(
            std::numeric_limits<float>::has_quiet_NaN ?(
               []{return float_M(a.data/b.data);}
            ): &_divide_noNaN
         ): &_divide_noNaN
      /*): &_divide_noSign*/
//...
#endif
}
```

It's ugly (have funtion pointer), but prevents unnesesery jumps at runtime. I hope c++23 will have better macros.

Also, more links:

- [About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)
- [User-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)
- [No const funtion pointers (1*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506094/const-function-pointers)

Follow-up: [Can floats not suport negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72138837/can-floats-not-suport-negative-or-even-0)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724359/are-there-any-modern-platforms-with-non-ieee-c-c-float-formats

Comment: Note that IEEE-754 was updated in 2008.   The major changes related to floating-point decimal arithmetic, though there were probably other cleanups.

Comment: `so that code is logicly the same on multiple platforms and compilators (like int_least16_t for int)` Err... `std::int_least16_t` is an example of code that is *not* logically  the same on multiple platforms.

Comment: @eerorika , can you tell more? `std::int_least16_t` can be 18bits so bit operations will be logiclly difrent, but `int_least` is for holding numbers of predictable size. `int` literal grows in size with years, so it's not `at least 16` but 32 or more...? ...or am I wrong...?

Comment: @AlexWąsowicz `int` is at least 16 bits. It may be more than 16 bits. It's usually the same as the "word" size of the CPU, although that doesn't mean much in the context of CPU architectures that have multiple word sizes (e.g. modern x86). `std::int_least16_t` is the smallest integer type that is at least 16 bits. It may be more than 16 bits on architectures that don't have 16 bit types.

Comment: is_iec559, Proper adherence to `is_iec559` is challenging for a compiler to test such that a compiler may adhere to `iec559` and not set that true - not worth the testing cost to be 100% compliant.  IOWs, `is_iec559 == false` doesn't mean implementation is not compliant.

Comment: " I can't use bit representation (in a safe manner)." --> I think this get to the root issue.  Why do you think you need this? Consider posting the higher level problem you are attempting to find a solution - it may not require a certain bit representation.  There is a good change your code is not compliant even if `is_iec559()` is true.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica that's good question, I cosider it because it can be done in raw c. But after reading answers, I thing it's best to use it like "black box" end just use math (like log to get exponent). I will just make casting from float_t to bits_t illegal. I will try to make some math functions. But I still don't know what to do with posible math errors (no infinity or NaN value problem).

Comment: @AlexWąsowicz See `frexpf()` to break a floating-point number into a normalized fraction and an integral power of 2.

Comment: "Which means that float MAY be unsigned": no it doesn't. It means it can support negative zero. Not the same thing at all.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Out of curiosity: do you know about any C implementation using non-IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic? E.g. based on Unum.

Comment: @pmor CCS used to use [this](https://www.ccsinfo.com/faq.php?page=mchp_float_format).

Comment: @pmor Note that "non-IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic" could be asserted if even 1 of the 100s of IEEE 754 requirements were not met.  I suspect today, many implementation only support most of IEEE 754 and not all.  Many of the rounding modes, sub-normal and other esoteric parts are difficult.

Comment: Re: "if even 1 of the 100s of IEEE 754 requirements were not met": yes, exactly. In that case it should be "_completely_ non-IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic". I wonder if formally verified FPUs (e.g. by Intel) are (fully) IEEE 754 conforming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, the value of [`std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559) shall be `true` for all floating-point types `T` [*"if, and only if, the type adheres to ISO/IEC/IEEE 60559"*](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.limits#lib:is_iec559,numeric_limits) and ISO/IEC/IEEE 60559:2011 is the same as IEEE 754-2008, so:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559 << '\n';
}
```

Note: As noted in the comments, some implementations may still report `true` for this constant even though their floating point types are not following the IEEE 754-2008 standard to the letter.

For example, in `gcc`, you can compile with the options `-Ofast` or `-ffast-math` which in turn sets a number of options which can result in incorrect output for programs that depend on an exact implementation of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions.

---

In [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (and later), there are conditional feature macros, `__STDC_IEC_559__` and `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__`, that, if available in your implementation, will tell you if it's conforming to IEC 60559:1989 / IEEE 754−1985.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
#ifdef __STDC_IEC_559__
    puts("true");
#endif
}
```

Note that if `__STDC_IEC_559__` is *not* defined, it doesn't necessarily mean that the implementation doesn't use IEEE 754 floats. It could just mean that it doesn't have these conditional feature macros. One interesting note about these macros is that if you use `-Ofast` or `-ffast-math` in `gcc`, they will not be defined (unlike in the C++ test).

The actual revision of the IEC / IEEE standards used changed in [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and [C17/18](https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf) and in [C23](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2731.pdf) (draft) there will be a number of new macros related to floating points and it (currently) refers to ISO/IEC 60559:2020 and IEEE 754-2019 which contains minor upgrades to IEC 60559:2011 / IEEE 754-2008.

Comment: Note that this may be true even if compiler is configured to not follow IEEE-754 exactly.

Comment: @eerorika Would that be compliant? [The standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.limits#lib:is_iec559,numeric_limits) says _"`true` if and only if the type adheres to ISO/IEC/IEEE 60559."_ and it has a note saying: _"ISO/IEC/IEEE 60559:2011 is the same as IEEE 754-2008._".

Comment: Technically not.

Comment: @eerorika Oh, that's nasty :) Nevertheless, I added a note about it to the answer. Are you thinking about `-Ofast`, `-ffast-math` etc. in gcc/clang? If so I could add a note about that too.

Comment: Such optimisations are exactly what I'm thinking.

Comment: @eerorika Great! Note added! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: For C, you can check the macro `__STDC_IEC_559__`; if it is defined, then the same applies.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks! I added some notes about that too.

Comment: @Turtlefight: That's now how C++ "Undefined Behavior" works. Where the C++ Standard says that behavior is Undefined, any outcome is acceptable. "Infinity" is therefore also acceptable. it's not just C++ versus IEEE754; you have similar things with C++ and POSIX.

Comment: @Turtlefight Have a look: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65189865/how-stdc-iec-559-affects-ub-gaps) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65106621/fp-invalid-operation-contradiction-between-c-ub-and-ieee-754-wdb).

Comment: @MSalters @​pmor you're right, for most cases compilers are allowed to be IEEE-conforming. One small exception to this seems to be constant expressions, which explicitly disallow most forms of undefined behaviour (including division by zero) ([[expr.const] 5.7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#5.7)) - so it seems like compilers are not allowed to be IEEE-conforming within contexts that require constant expressions (like template parameters, e.g. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/G7qbs69Te)).