# Can floats not suport negative or even 0?

Tags: c, floating-point, language-lawyer, standards

It's follow-up question to:
[How to detect non IEEE-754 float, and how to use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72032458/how-to-detect-non-ieee-754-float-and-how-to-use-them)

In theory, can we assume that c float always support negative numbers?

Comment: I'd say yes, and not only in theory. An unsigned floating point type wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: OK to not support -0.0.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: It *could* be implemented, but the semantics of the subtraction operator would be wonky (unlike unsigned ints which have sane modulo-2^n wraparound behavior).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can floats not suport negative or even 0?

I don't think the intention is to allow not supporting negative or zero:

> ISO/IEC9899:2017
>
> Characteristics of floating types <float.h>
>
> ... The following parameters are used to define the model for each floating-point
> type:
>
> - s sign (±1)
> - b base or radix of exponent representation (an integer > 1)
> - e exponent (an integer between a minimum emin and a maximum emax)
> - p precision (the number of base-b digits in the significand)
> - fk nonnegative integers less than b (the significand digits)
>
> [image: float formula]

C23 wording adds stronger assertion

> ISO/IEC 9899:202x (E)
>
> Floating types shall be able to represent zero (all fk == 0) and all normalized floating-point numbers
> (f1 > 0 and all possible k digits and e exponents result in values representable in the type

Answer (score 0):

If you speak about "floating point types" in general (and not about the type named `float`) when using the word "floats":

**Yes**:

If you design a compiler, you might define the non-standard type `unsigned float` with 24 mantissa bits, 8 exponent bits, no sign bit and 256 possible exponent values (instead of 254).

Such a floating point format would only be able to store positive values (not equal to zero) and infinite or NaN would also not be supported.

The advantage of such a format would be a wider range and/or a higher precision than a `float` data type with the same number of bits.